# ¿Cómo obtener solo 2 decimales en una operación matemática en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy realizando una calculadora con reactjs y todo esta bien, mi único problema es que quiero que el resultado cuando tenga parte decimal mande solo **dos** decimales al input, eso lo consigo hacer con `toFixed(2)` solo que cuando el resultado es un numero entero manda los dos decimales también `20.00`.

¿Cómo hago para que solo mande los decimales cuando el numero no sea entero?

Aquí adjunto evento del resultado

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
// import App from './App';

const Calculator = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Buttons />
    </div>
  );
};

class Buttons extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentValue: '0',
    };
    this.handleAddDecimals = this.handleAddDecimals.bind(this);
    this.handleEvaluate = this.handleEvaluate.bind(this);
    this.handleClear = this.handleClear.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick = value => {
    const { currentValue } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      currentValue: currentValue === '0' ? String(value) : currentValue + value,
    });
  };

  handleAddDecimals = () => {
    const { currentValue } = this.state;
    if (currentValue.indexOf('.') === -1) {
      this.setState({
        currentValue: currentValue + '.',
      });
    }
  };

  handleEvaluate = () => {
    const { currentValue } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      currentValue: eval(currentValue),
    });
  };

  // handleEvaluate = () => {
  //   const { currentValue } = this.state;
  //   let fixedNum =
  //     currentValue % 1 === 0
  //       ? parseFloat(currentValue).toFixed(0)
  //       : parseFloat(currentValue).toFixed(2);
  //   this.setState({
  //     currentValue: eval(fixedNum),
  //   });
  // };


  handleClear = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentValue: '0',
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { currentValue } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <input id="display" value={currentValue} />
        <div className="button-div">
          <button id="zero" onClick={() => this.handleClick(0)}>
            0
          </button>
          <button id="one" onClick={() => this.handleClick(1)}>
            1
          </button>
          <button id="two" onClick={() => this.handleClick(2)}>
            2
          </button>
          <button id="three" onClick={() => this.handleClick(3)}>
            3
          </button>
          <button id="four" onClick={() => this.handleClick(4)}>
            4
          </button>
          <button id="five" onClick={() => this.handleClick(5)}>
            5
          </button>
          <button id="six" onClick={() => this.handleClick(6)}>
            6
          </button>
          <button id="seven" onClick={() => this.handleClick(7)}>
            7
          </button>
          <button id="eight" onClick={() => this.handleClick(8)}>
            8
          </button>
          <button id="nine" onClick={() => this.handleClick(9)}>
            9
          </button>

          <button id="add" onClick={() => this.handleClick('+')}>
            +
          </button>
          <button id="subtract" onClick={() => this.handleClick('-')}>
            -
          </button>
          <button id="multiply" onClick={() => this.handleClick('*')}>
            *
          </button>
          <button id="divide" onClick={() => this.handleClick('/')}>
            /
          </button>
          <button id="decimal" onClick={this.handleAddDecimals}>
            .
          </button>
          <button id="equals" onClick={this.handleEvaluate}>
            =
          </button>
          <button id="clear" onClick={this.handleClear}>
            C
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la operación que te manda 20.00 en el resultado? O algúna otra operación con la que estes haciendo la prueba del caso que nos reportas, saludos

Comment: No me es posible emular el problema que describes con el código de la pregunta, no veo ningún problema de mi lado, la calculadora funciona bien ¿Podrías verificar?

Comment: `handleEvaluate = () => {
    const { currentValue } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      currentValue: eval(currentValue),
    });
  };
`
cuando el resultado retorna un entero colocandole el toFixed(2) a la función eval me retorna los .00 y al sustituirla con el codigo que esta comentado deja de funcionar

Comment: Justo actualizé la respuesta, el componente ya funciona como necesitas, lo verifique de mi lado, quedo en espera de tus comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con esta versión del método `handleEvaluate`, en tu `App`:

```
  handleEvaluate = () => {
    const { currentValue } = this.state;
    let resultToCast = eval(currentValue);
    
    let fixedResult =
       (resultToCast % 1 === 0)
         ? resultToCast.toFixed(0)
         : resultToCast.toFixed(2);
    
    this.setState({
      currentValue: fixedResult,
    });
  };
```

#### Notas de campo

Se recíbe un dato tipo `string` en `this.state`, el método `eval` ejecuta la operación aritmética en su versión `string`, regresa un tipo `number`:

```js
    //const { currentValue } = this.state;
    const currentValue = "6/2";
    console.log("string: ",currentValue);
    console.log(typeof currentValue);
    let resultToCast = eval(currentValue);
    console.log("resultToCast", resultToCast);
    console.log(typeof resultToCast);
```

Luego, se verifica si el número dentro de `resultToCast` es entero, esto se hace con el [operador reminder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder); además, se hace uso de una validación con el operador condicional.

Dependiendo del resultado de esta validación, se usa `toFixed` para dejar dos decimales(fraccionario) o ninguno, con su valor por default **0** (entero):

```
(resultToCast % 1 === 0)
         ? resultToCast.toFixed(0)
         : resultToCast.toFixed(2);
```

> Nótese que hasta este punto, `resultToCast` es de tipo `number`.

Al aplicar el método `toFixed` a `resultToCast`, también se hace un [Cast](https://isaaccomputerscience.org/concepts/prog_string_casting) , con esto se transforma `resultToCast` de tipo `number` a tipo `string`, tal y como venía desde `this.state`.

Finalmente, el resultado de la validación se asigna a `fixedResult`:

```
let fixedResult = (resultToCast % 1 === 0) ? resultToCast.toFixed(0) : resultToCast.toFixed(2);
```

Aquí, un ejemplo en JS:

```js
const handleEvaluate = (expresion) => {
    //const { currentValue } = this.state;
    const currentValue = expresion;
    console.log("expresion: ",currentValue);
    console.log(typeof currentValue);
    let resultToCast = eval(currentValue);
    console.log("resultToCast", resultToCast);
    console.log(typeof resultToCast);
    let fixedResult = (resultToCast % 1 === 0) ? resultToCast.toFixed(0) : resultToCast.toFixed(2);
    console.log("fixedResult", fixedResult);
    console.log(typeof fixedResult);
    /* React stuff
    this.setState({
      currentValue: fixedResult,
    });*/
  };
  
  handleEvaluate("6/2");//entero
  handleEvaluate("4/3");//fraccionario
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Esta muy interesante tu respuesta, pero al aplicarla no me funciona... Primer error que me arroja es ´currentValue.toFixed is not a function´, eso lo intento solucionar con un `parseFloat(currentValue).toFixed(2);` pero al incluirle mi funcion eval() deja de funcionar, incluire mi codigo completo en la pregunta, creo que estoy declarando alguna cosa mal

Comment: Lo reviso y te mando una nueva versión

Comment: **Excelente!** me ha funcionado, muchisimas gracias y excelente explicación, realmente entendi la logica ahora.

Comment: Qué bien, es un buen ejercicio para estudiar tipos de datos, si consideras que la respuesta fue útil puedes votar por ella, suerte y salud.

Comment: Fui de mucha utilidad amigo!, nuevamente gracias y ya vote por ella pero.. debido a que no tengo reputación suficiente aun mi voto no aparece publicamente...

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar la funcion `Number()` de javascript para solucionarlo o su version corta

que es colocando un simbolo de `+` antes de la variable.

ejemplo:

```js
entero = 4;
decimal = 2.33;

etf = entero.toFixed(2);
dtf= decimal.toFixed(2);

// decimal
numberDecimal = Number(dtf);
console.log(numberDecimal )
// entero
numberEntero = Number(etf)
console.log(numberEntero )

// forma corta "se coloca el simbolo + delante"
console.log(+etf )
console.log(+dtf )
```